# Databinding adapter doesn't provide data to recycler view

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I have 2 fragments in my mvvm application that both have different view models but fetch data from the same repository. The first one shows a list of entities which are presented in the recycler view, the second one is for adding a new entity to the database. I also use data binding in my application. The problem appears, when I navigate from the first fragment to the second one and then update room data by adding a new entity to it, but when I pop up to the first on - my recycler view is void.
I tried debugging it, and the data is always provided to the Livedata variable of the first fragment ViewModel, but then, when it's processed in Databinding adapter, it's void for some reason. I also tried solutions suggested, including swapping Lifecycleowner and ViewModel binding declarations, but it hasn't helped me in any way. Thank you, guys, for helping in advance!

My fragment 1 code :

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment(),
NoteCardAdapter.NoteTouchListener,PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener,
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    private var _binding : FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val adapter by lazy {
        NoteCardAdapter(this as NoteCardAdapter.NoteTouchListener)
    }

    private val vm : HomeViewModel by viewModels()

    private val noteSharedViewModel : NoteSharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private var currentOption : SortOption = SortOption.ByDate

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        binding.adapter = adapter
        binding.vm = vm

        vm.sortNotes(currentOption)

        binding.apply {
            homeRecyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
            homeRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context)
            homeRecyclerView.itemAnimator= NotesItemAnimator()
        }
        binding.homeSearchView.isSubmitButtonEnabled  = true
        binding.homeSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this as SearchView.OnQueryTextListener)

        binding.addNoteButton.setOnClickListener{
            val note = Note(
                "","","",false, activity?.getDate(), folderId = -1
            )
            noteSharedViewModel.selectNote(note)
            val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToSingleNoteFragment(
                isNew = true
            )

            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }

        binding.ibSort.setOnClickListener{
            showSortMenu()
        }

        binding.foldersButton.setOnClickListener{
            findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToFoldersFragment())
        }
    }
```

Fragment 1 viewmodel code :

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor (
    private val noteRepository : NoteRepository
) : ViewModel() {


    private val _notesLiveData  = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Note>>()
    val notesLiveData : LiveData<ArrayList<Note>> = _notesLiveData

    private var currentJob : Job = Job()

    fun searchNotes(query : String, option: SortOption){
        currentJob.cancel()
        currentJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            noteRepository.searchAllNotes(query, option).cancellable().collect{
                _notesLiveData.postValue(it as ArrayList<Note>)
            }
        }
    }

    fun sortNotes(option: SortOption){
        currentJob.cancel()
        currentJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            noteRepository.getAllNotes(option).cancellable().collect{
                _notesLiveData.postValue(it as ArrayList<Note>)
            }
        }
    }

    fun deleteNote(note : Note){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            noteRepository.deleteNote(note)
        }
    }

    fun updateNoteChecked(note : Note){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            noteRepository.insertNote(note, false)
        }
    }

}
```

Databinding adapter code :

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("submitNoteList")
fun submitNoteList(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data : ArrayList<Note>?){
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as NoteCardAdapter
    adapter.setData((data ?: arrayListOf()))
    Log.d("Debug", "Submitted ${data?.size.toString()} items to recyclerview")
}
```

Recycler view xml code :

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            tools:listitem="@layout/note_card_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
            android:id="@+id/homeRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="10dp"
            android:layout_height="515dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            app:setNoteAdapter="@{adapter}"
            app:submitNoteList="@{vm.notesLiveData}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvRecentTitle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
```

Comment: Set layoutmanager before setting up adapter.

Comment: It's still not working after setting it

Comment: Check your response... Otherwise you've to debug or set data in your kt class without datbinding... May be you can find root cause

Comment: BindingAdapter("submitNoteList") in the log are you getting size?

Comment: Yes, I receive a list of items, but then I immediately receive a null pointer. It happens only in the case when I pop back from another fragment for some reason. For example, when the fragment is instantiated recycler view shows everything well

Comment: Yes, I get size there

Answer (score 0):

First I would test that the recyclerView is actually getting data from the view model by manually creating a test object and inserting it into the list of objects to be displayed by the onBindViewHolder.

example:
in your adapter

```
class NotesAdapter(val notesList: List<Notes>): RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NotesViewHolder>(){
var notes:List<Notes> = emptyList()
set(value){
    field = value
notes.add(Note("Date","Test Note Title","Test Note Content")) //test if adapter works
notes.add(noteList) // test if data from view model works
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.viewDataBinding.also {
                it.notes = notes[position]
                
    }
}
```

You can pass data from your activity to the view holder since it now requires a list of notes
if that works use an observer to the fragment/activity that refreshes the notes from your data source when the data changes